# Accessing nested value in loop in json using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to fetch the value of each api3 in this json object where each array has api3 value.

```
 {
    "count": 10,
    "result": [
    {
            "type": "year",
            "year": {
                "month": {
                    "api1": {
                        "href": "https://Ap1.com"
                    },
                    "api2": {
                        "href": "FETCH-CONTENT"
                    },
                    "api3": {
                        "href": "https://Ap3.com"
                    },
                    "api4": {
                        "href": "https://Ap4.com"
                    }
                },
                "id": "sdvnkjsnvj",
                "summary": "summeryc",
                "type": "REST",
                "apiId": "mlksmfmksdfs",
                "idProvider": {
                    "id": "sfsmkfmskf",
                    "name": "Apikey"
                },
                "tags": []
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "year1",
            "year": {
                "month": {
                    "api1": {
                        "href": "https://Ap11.com"
                    },
                    "api2": {
                        "href": "FETCH-CONTENT-1"
                    },
                    "api3": {
                        "href": "https://Ap13.com"
                    },
                    "api4": {
                        "href": "https://Ap14.com"
                    }
                },
                "id": "sdvnkjsnvj",
                "summary": "summeryc",
                "type": "REST",
                "apiId": "mlksmfmksdfs",
                "idProvider": {
                    "id": "sfsmkfmskf",
                    "name": "Apikey"
                },
                "tags": []
            }
        },
```

I am able to get the whole json object and first value inside it.

```
with open('C:\python\examplee.json','r+') as fr:
data = json.load(fr)
print(data["result"])
```

Thank you in advance for helping me figuring this.

Comment: `print([i["year"]["month"]["api3"]["href"] for i in data["result"]])`?

Comment: You just need to choose the correct indexes and keys to deal with @RJ_Singh check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element in list of result key, get the value for the nested dictionary within item

```
print([item['year']['month']['api3'] for item in data['result']])
```

The output will be `[{'href': 'https://Ap3.com'}, {'href': 'https://Ap13.com'}]`

Or if you want to get the `href` value as well

```
print([item['year']['month']['api3']['href'] for item in data['result']])
```

The output will be

```
['https://Ap3.com', 'https://Ap13.com']
```

So your whole code will look like

```
data = {}
with open('C:\python\examplee.json','r+') as fr:
    data = json.load(fr)

print([item['year']['month']['api3']['href'] for item in dct['result']])
```

Comment: Thanks @Devesh.. But it is not working i tried putting multiple combination to get the href option but no luck so far.

Comment: Your solution works absolutely fine @Devesh with the json provided in the question.Now i am facing difficulty because there is slight changes in my json file. All fields are same in all the elements except one of the fields doesn't match.That is why it is not working.

Comment: Absolutely @Devesh Thanks a bunch ..:)

Comment: But what would be the approach if we have json file with the same file content and one element is having different field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193368/discussion-between-rj-singh-and-devesh-kumar-singh).

Comment: What will be the approach if the jason file is not having consistent elements and we want to fetch the values from few elements. As the above one does work if all the elements are consistent  and having similar key.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your JSON schema is static so you can just use this:

`print([x['year']['month']['api3']['href'] for x in data['result']])`

will return you:

`['https://Ap3.com', 'https://Ap13.com']`